# Preprocessor directive Impossible define or cancel defining the preprocessor

Tags: c#

I'm trying to learn preprocessor directive, so I made a simple example like this:

```
using System;

namespace learning
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
#define DEBUG
            test();
        }

        private void test()
        {
#if DEBUG
            Console.WriteLine("Debug mode");
#elif RELEASE
            Console.WriteLine("Release mode");
#else
            Console.WriteLine("Debug and release don't defined");
#endif
        }

    }
}
```

but I got unfortunately this error:

> Impossible to define or cancel defining the preprocessor symbols after the first token in the file

I take this example from a programming book, what is wrong?

**update (my solution):**

```
#define RELEASE
using System;

namespace learning
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
#if DEBUG
            Console.WriteLine("Debug mode");
#elif RELEASE
            Console.WriteLine("Release mode");
#else
            Console.WriteLine("Debug and release don't defined");
#endif
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

printed result: `Debug mode`, but should be `Release mode`. What I did wrong?

Comment: Put #define DEBUG at the beginning of the file.

Comment: The book is wrong, basically. Which book is it? Name and shame... (I'm really hoping it isn't mine...)

Comment: @JonSkeet http://antoniopelleriti.it/page/libro-csharp

Comment: I note that the code is invalid due to calling an instance method from a static method without an explicit target, too...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Neo mentioned, you can define it at the top of your file.

Or, if you want for it to be global, and you are using Visual Studio, you could define it in your project properties (right-click on the project, choose Properties, then go to the Build tab).

That screen would allow you to define the symbol based upon the build configuration (so you could set your symbol for debug builds and have it automatically be removed when you switch configurations).

If you are not using Visual Studio, you could pass your conditional symbols to MSBuild or csc (the command line build or command line c# compiler).  All of these options would give you the ability to set/unset symbols without changing the source code.

Comment: Got it, but is possible define more symbols?

Comment: @Dillinger: You can define as many symbols as you like at the start of each file, and also in the project settings. You can't define more symbols once you're into "normal" code.

Comment: Yep, you can define as many as you want -- just put them in the "Conditional Compilation symbols" in the Build Tab.

Comment: Up voting as this is a more complete answer than mine.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the `#define` line at the very start of the file, before the `using` statements

Comment: Oh, there is no refence of this in the book. I got it now. But I have update the example putting `#define RELEASE` at the top of all, why the compiler print me: `Debug mode` instead of `Release mode`?

Comment: @Dillinger: My guess is that you're building it in Visual Studio in a debug configuration, where DEBUG is already defined in the project settings.

Comment: Have a look at my answer below, but in addition to debug symbols, you can have build configurations.  This allows you set a group of options and have them apply to a specific configuration.  For example, By default, you get "Debug" and "Release" configurations when you create a project.  Debug has the DEBUG symbol enabled, and compiler optimizations turned off.  Release turns on compile optimizations (there are other differences as well).  Have a look at the  Configuration Manager (right-click on the solution).

Comment: @JonSkeet You're right.. I turn on release mode and now the console print the correct result.